# In Matthew 7:16, are the "fruits" by which a "wolf" is known their "works" or their "doctrine"?

Tags: matthew

Matthew 7:16 New American Standard Bible (NASB)

> 16 You will [a]know them by ***their fruits***. [b]Grapes are not gathered from thorn bushes nor figs from thistles, are they?

Be trying to find from the context what exactly the fruits are,but i have failed

Are they:

1) External works

or

2) Doctrine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 15 “Beware of the false prophets, who come to you in sheep’s clothing, but inwardly are ravenous wolves. 16 You will know them by their fruits.

Them = false prophets

Fruits = that which originates or comes from something, an effect, result
work, act, deed

The immediate context does not give the definition of what these 'fruits' will be.  We do know that "know them" specifically refers to false prophets.  This verse does not mean this is a way in which one would identify 'true' believers as many have taught the last 100 years.  So how does one identify a false prophets?  I believe the OT has a few clues.

> Deut. 13:1-4 “If a prophet or someone who has dreams arises among you
>   and proclaims a sign or wonder to you, 2 and that sign or wonder he
>   has promised you comes about, but he says, ‘Let us follow other gods,’
>   which you have not known, ‘and let us worship them,’ 3 do not listen
>   to that prophet’s words or to that dreamer. For the Lord your God is
>   testing you to know whether you love the Lord your God with all your
>   heart and all your soul. 4 You must follow the Lord your God and fear
>   Him.
>
> Deut. 18:22  22 When a prophet speaks in the name of the Lord, if the
>   thing does not come about or come true, that is the thing which the
>   Lord has not spoken. The prophet has spoken it presumptuously; you
>   shall not be afraid of him.

Comment: Welcome to the site :) Relevant verses from the OT. +1

Answer (score 2):

Here are some examples of good and bad actions and doctrine fruitage:-

> NWT  Galatians 5:19-26
>   "Now the works of the flesh are plainly seen, and they are sexual immorality, uncleanness, brazen conduct, 20 idolatry, spiritism, hostility, strife, jealousy, fits of anger, dissensions, divisions, sects, 21 envy, drunkenness, wild parties, and things like these. I am forewarning you about these things, the same way I already warned you, that those who practice such things will not inherit God’s Kingdom.
>
> 22 On the other hand, the fruitage of the spirit is love, joy, peace, patience, kindness, goodness, faith, 23 mildness, self-control. Against such things there is no law. 24 Moreover, those who belong to Christ Jesus have nailed to the stake the flesh together with its passions and desires.
>
> 25 If we are living by spirit, let us also go on walking orderly by spirit. 26 Let us not become egotistical, stirring up competition with one another, envying one another."
>
> NWT 1 Peter 4:3 "For the time that has passed by is sufficient for you to have done the will of the nations when you carried on in acts of brazen conduct, unbridled passions, overdrinking, wild parties, drinking bouts, and lawless idolatries."
>
> NWT James 3:17-18  "But the wisdom from above is first of all pure, then peaceable, reasonable, ready to obey, full of mercy and good fruits, impartial, not hypocritical. 18 Moreover, the fruit of righteousness is sown in peaceful conditions for those who are making peace."
>
> NWT  Titus 1:5-9  "I left you in Crete so that you would correct the things that were defective and make appointments of elders in city after city, as I instructed you: 6 if there is any man free from accusation, a husband of one wife, having believing children who are not accused of debauchery or rebelliousness. 7 For as God’s steward, an overseer must be free from accusation, not self-willed, not quick-tempered, not a drunkard, not violent, not greedy of dishonest gain, 8 but hospitable, a lover of goodness, sound in mind, righteous, loyal, self-controlled, 9 holding firmly to the faithful word as respects his art of teaching, so that he may be able both to encourage by the teaching that is wholesome and to reprove those who contradict."
>
> NWT James 4:1-3  "What is the source of the wars and fights among you? Do they not originate from your fleshly desires that carry on a conflict within you? 2 You desire, and yet you do not have. You go on murdering and coveting, and yet you are not able to obtain. You go on fighting and waging war. You do not have because of your not asking. 3 When you do ask, you do not receive because you are asking for a wrong purpose, so that you may spend it on your fleshly desires."
>
> NWT 2 Peter 2:1-3 "However, there also came to be false prophets among the people, as there will also be false teachers among you. These will quietly bring in destructive sects, and they will even disown the owner who bought them, bringing speedy destruction upon themselves. 2 Furthermore, many will follow their brazen conduct, and because of them the way of the truth will be spoken of abusively. 3 Also, they will greedily exploit you with counterfeit words. But their judgment, decided long ago, is not moving slowly, and their destruction is not sleeping."

Both are works of doctrine or ones theology. Example; "a just war" doctrine will produce vile works!

Comment: That is a nice selection of relevant verses, +1. So would you say "works" or "doctrine" or what? Thanks.

Comment: @Rumiator  Both are works of doctrine or ones theology.  Example; "a just war" doctrine will produce vile works!

Comment: Please add that to your answer. Comments often "go away. But I think the question would be one or the other because the fruit I should think is different from the root, no?

Comment: @ Ruminator  OK?

Comment: "Example; "a just war" doctrine will produce vile works!" What does the just war have about it that produces bad fruits? You realize just war teaches that one's country has a right to defend itself against foreign countries and such, right? They don't bear the sword in vain...

Comment: So which is the "fruit"? Is it the Just War Doctrine or the resulting war? And where is it identified in the scriptures you cited? Thanks.

Comment: @Sola Gretia James 4:1-4 What is the source of the wars and fights among you? Do they not originate from your fleshly desires that carry on a conflict within you? ...You go on murdering and coveting, and yet you are not able to obtain. You go on fighting and waging war. ...  When you do ask, you do not receive because you are asking for a wrong purpose, so that you may spend it on your fleshly desires. Adulteresses, do you not know that friendship with the world is enmity with God? Whoever, therefore, wants to be a friend of the world is making himself an enemy of God.

Comment: @ Ruminator "Brazen Conduct"  See William Barcley on the Greek "aselgeia."

Comment: @ethos "wars and fights" here refer to 'fights' and 'murder' and 'coveting' and thus bad wars, i.e. 'fighting.' Not defense of your country or countrymen as a sovereign, which isn't for coveting and envying and jealously or gain. Do they bear the sword in vain, due to their fleshly desires? No, they mete out the justice of God. Besides, the war *does* originate in sin, but not the necessary evil of partaking in it once begun (Rev 12:7).

Comment: @Sola Gratia  The standaerd is at Luke 6:27, 28  "But I [Jesus] say to you who are listening: Continue to LOVE YOUR ENEMIES, to do good to those hating you, 28 to bless those cursing you, to pray for those who are insulting you."   Hebrews 12:14   Pursue peace with ALL PEOPLE and the sanctification without which no man will see the Lord.
 End of story!

Comment: You are abusing Scripture. This is telling people to love your enemy. What is love? To genuinely will the good of the other. This is not incompatible with chopping their head off, if it's a just war, since you don't WANT to hurt them. That's the point. They are coming to do much greater sin to yours, and to prevent such an evil, you must use your God-given powers to defend your men, women, and children from puppets of Satan who whether you love them or not in this instance, will continue to do what they are doing. You give them a chance of course, but that's just war in a nutshell.

Comment: Besides, angels aren't exempt from loving their enemies, and their interpretation of Jesus' moral law proves me right, because they went to a just war with evil angels. Again, Revelation 12:7. You are misapplying Jesus' teaching. It's very simple.

Comment: @Sola Gratia Genesis 9:6 Anyone shedding man’s blood, by man will his own blood be shed, for in God’s image He made man. &  Matthew 26:52  "Then Jesus said to him: “Return your sword to its place, for all those who take up the sword will perish by the sword.

Comment: These don't trump verses talking specifically about just war I'm afraid. They have their respective contexts to be respected ("anyone shedding blood" not applying to "thou shalt not suffer a witch to live" etc.).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86417/discussion-between-ethos-and-sola-gratia).

Answer (score 0):

The fruits of the false prophets are the blasphemous promises of the many forms of the doctrines of prosperity, power and passion that is so popular in these times.